# ZeroC Ice connection events

Tags: ice

How can I know on the server side when a client connected or disconnected from server?

Does ZeroC Ice provides some callback functions for those events?

Minimal demo:

Server side

```
try(com.zeroc.Ice.Communicator communicator = com.zeroc.Ice.Util.initialize(args))
    {
        com.zeroc.Ice.ObjectAdapter adapter =
            communicator.createObjectAdapterWithEndpoints("Hello", "default -h localhost -p 10000");
        adapter.add(new HelloI(), com.zeroc.Ice.Util.stringToIdentity("hello"));
        adapter.activate();
        communicator.waitForShutdown();
    }
```

Client side

```
    try(com.zeroc.Ice.Communicator communicator = com.zeroc.Ice.Util.initialize(args))
    {
        HelloPrx hello = HelloPrx.checkedCast(communicator.stringToProxy("hello:default -h localhost -p 10000"));
        hello.sayHello();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Server side you can check `current.con` member and register a close callback if it's a connection that hasn't been seen before see [setCloseCallback](https://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice37/Ice-Connection#Ice-Connection-setCloseCallback)

current is `com.zeroc.Ice.Current` parameter passed to all servant methods, for example in `sayHello` implementation you can do

```
@Override
public void sayHello(int delay, com.zeroc.Ice.Current current)
{
    // Check if current.con is a new connection, you will 
    // need to keep track of that in your code.

    // Install a close callback for the connection.
    current.con.setCloseCallback(con ->
       {
            // Close callback
       });
}
```

Comment: code example (I don't really get it when you say `current.con`) ? Who's `current` ?

Comment: `current` object is pass by the server dispatch to all methods, the `con` member of the `current` object represent the connection used to dispatch the invocation